# Plot a distribution curve curve in R

Tags: curve

What are the alternatives for drawing a simple curve for a function like

0, from -∞ to 0

x^2, from 0 to (3)^(1/3)

1, from (3)^(1/3) to ∞

look that my attempt is incomplet

```
curve(x^2, from=0, to=(3)^(1/3), xlab="x", ylab="y")
```

I hope I didn't write a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify a function that fits your problem:

```
> f <- function(x) ifelse(x < 0, 0, ifelse(x<3^(1/3), x^2, 1))
> curve(f, from = -5, to = 5)
```